# How do you update data model to prevent tableview cells from repeating data?

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

[Data Model Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DMiq.png)

I have a form inside a table view pulling data from PHP. I am using reusable cells and have textfield inside every cell (300 cells). The problem is when I scroll down the page the data inside the textfields repeat. What I am trying to do is update the cells data to prevent the repeat. How would I change the value inside the data? (ex "units = 0 changed to units = 50)? And will doing this prevent the repeating data?

Comment: You have to save the current editing text somewhere and then when the cell is load, just assign the saved text back to the text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This repeate because the cell is Reuse. You should save each current editing content of textfield, and set it in tableCellForRow.

Comment: I understand what youre saying. How would you save it though? I was thinking there's a way to update my data model.

Comment: as I see, you pull data and show to your tableView and use can edit it right?. If this true, you can create a variable to track editing state, and check editing state to show value you want in cellForRowAtIndex ``` let configItem = isEditing ? editedItems[indexPath.row] : items[indexPath.row]   .... cell.config(configItem)```

Comment: oh, how and when you save the update data? each time user change value in textField, or when user tap at some button... ?